# Duplicate values Error on Non-Index, Non-Unique property change

Tags: jet-ef-provider

I ask a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809921/duplicate-values-in-the-index-primary-key-or-relationship/44825749#44825749), but this is a different situation that results in the same error message.

I am updating an NON-index, NON-unique property, PageNumber.

And I am receiving the following error

> OleDbException: The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.

```
public void DoRenumberPages(object blah)
{


    var hiddenPages = projectDB.Pages.AsEnumerable().Where(x => !IsVisibleDrawing(x.DrawingType) && x.DrawingType != 3001).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenPages.Count(); i++)
    {                
        hiddenPages[i].PageNumber = i + 1000;
    }

    var TOCPages = projectDB.Pages.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.DrawingType == 3001).OrderBy(x => x.BookNumber).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < TOCPages.Count(); i++)
    {               
        TOCPages[i].PageNumber = i + 1;
    }

    var visiblePagesNotTOC = projectDB.Pages.AsEnumerable().Where(x => IsVisibleDrawing(x.DrawingType) && x.DrawingType != 3001).OrderBy(x => x.BookNumber).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < visiblePagesNotTOC.Count(); i++)
    {                
        visiblePagesNotTOC[i].PageNumber = i + TOCPages.Count() + 1;
    }


    projectDB.SaveChanges();

    RenumberPages.EnableExecute();

}
```

Page Model Class

```
[Table("Content")]
public class Page
{
    //** Primary Key
    [Column("Counter")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProjectCounter { get; set; }

    public short Version { get; set; }
    public short Revision { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }

    public int DrawingType { get; set; }
    //** Forign Key?
    public int DeviceLocationCounter { get; set; }
    //** Forign Key?
    public int FolderID { get; set; }

    [Column("Page")]
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    //** Indexed, Unique 
    public int BookNumber { get; set; }

    public string PageIndex { get; set; }

    //** Product 
    //** DrawingObject is not here

    public bool Update { get; set; }
    public short Flag { get; set; }        
}
```

ETA:

I have change `public int BookNumber { get; set; }` to `public int? BookNumber { get; set; }` This doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: If the primary key is an autonumbering field, the only other unique index is on BookNumber so you are creating duplicated BookNumber values. In this code is not clear where it is happening. There could be an issue related to BookNumber not nullable in the model and nullable on DB.

Comment: I have change `public int BookNumber { get; set; }` to `public int? BookNumber { get; set; }` This doesn't solve the issue. I can send you source code and access database if that will help.

Comment: If you send me a compilable example (with also data) I can check it

Comment: @bubi: Here is a zip with the solution, and databse. Just run the Test project. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsA1Mz52V5ZYg6RVOUldFiCekWrt_w

Comment: I think you developed the project with VS 2017... Anyway, I already tougth to install it but I need some days...

Comment: I write this in a normal answer becouse here there is not enough space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I could start the project.
The problem is the one I wrote here [duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809921/duplicate-values-in-the-index-primary-key-or-relationship/44825749#44825749). If you enable query printing setting `JetEntityFrameworkProvider.JetConnection.ShowSqlStatements = true;` somewhere (I did it in your `Test.Program.Main`) you can see the statements that EF runs. The first update query is

```
update [Content]
set [Page] = @p0
where ([Counter] = @p1)

@p0 = 3
@p1 = 2
```

If you look at the database, the time you run the query the `Page = 3` is already contained in the record with `Counter = 3`. You can't solve this problem also inside a transaction and also with other (next to all) DBMSs you have the same problem.

The only solution (if you need the unique index on `Page`) is to update in 2 different `SaveChanges`. For example:
1. Set `Page = null` then `SaveChanges()`
2. Set `Page = number` then `SaveChanges()`

Microsoft Access permits duplicated null values in unique indexes. If you will permit to use different databases you could have problems.

Comment: The page column is not listed as unique or an index in the database, but I still receive this error. If you open the database file in access you can see this. The password for the database is "SEEME"  by the way

Comment: The problem is on the indexes Name and NameDesc. They are both composite unique indexes. *EDIT*: you can try to make the same thing in Microsoft Access and you'll receive the same error.

Comment: What table is Name and NameDesc in? it is not in the Content table.

Comment: They are 2 unique indexes on the Content table. They both include Page column.

Comment: Ohh ok, that clarifies things. Thank you very much for your help especially since it turned out to be jet/access related and just EF-Jet-Provider related.

Comment: Post Note: I finally found where the Indexes are listed in MS Access. Only some of them were showing on the property view, which was confusing me.